# Filter duplicates from mysql result depending on column value

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates, distinct, rows

I'm having some problems working out how to return the desired rows from the following mysql table:

```
first_name      last_name      collection
==========================================
   Bob            Jones            1
   Ted            Jones            1
   Bob            Jones            1
   Bob            Jones            2
   Ted            Baker            2
```

I want to return the count of names based on columns 'first_name' and 'last_name'. Ordinarily it would just be a simple case of using 'group by first_name, last_name', so we would have the following result: a count of 3 for Bob Jones, 1 for Ted Jones, and 1 for Ted Baker.

However, the difficulty is the third column 'collection'. I need to exclude duplicate names between collections, but not within collections. So we'd include all names in the count for the first collection, but only include names in the count from the second collection if they do NOT occur in the first collection.

So, the desired result would be as follows: a count of 2 for Bob Jones, 1 for Ted Jones, and 1 for Ted Baker.

```
first_name      last_name      collection             included?
==========================================         ===============
   Bob            Jones            1                    Yes
   Ted            Jones            1                    Yes
   Bob            Jones            1                    Yes
   Bob            Jones            2                    No
   Ted            Baker            2                    Yes
```

I have really tried to get my head around this but I am starting to run out of ideas. Any help would be hugely appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT( DISTINCT collection) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

The COUNT DISTINCT would eliminate the duplicate Bob/Jones/1 records.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your answer, very quick! Unfortunately this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I think if we had three occurrences of bob jones in collection 1 and three occurrences of bob jones in collection 2, your suggested query would only return a count of 2 (one for each of the two collections), whereas in fact it should be 3 as there are three occurrences of bob jones in collection 1. In effect we just want to ignore that name if it crops up in another collection if it's already been counted, but include it if it hasn't.

Comment: I guess you could just do a regular `group by first,last,collection` grouping to get the per-collection counts, and then wrap that in another query to filter out the unwanted collections.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
SELECT u1.first_name, u1.last_name, u1.collection FROM users u1 
WHERE u1.collection = (SELECT min(u2.collection) 
    FROM users u2 WHERE u1.first_name = u2.first_name
    AND u1.last_name = u2.last_name);
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd086/7